# docker ps -q: command not found / docker stop : command not found

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to stop all of my Docker containers with:
`docker stop $(docker ps -q)`

However, this was the output:

```
docker ps -q: command not found
docker stop : command not found
```

The same applied to:
`docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`
with this output:

```
docker ps -aq: command not found
docker rm : command not found
```

[This](https://www.edureka.co/community/12166/ps-command-doesn-t-work-in-docker-container) forum answer outlined that apt-get update && apt-get install procps could help to get it working. However, this lead to the following error message:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

I am working with the Windows subsystem for Linux and execute this within Visual Studio Code.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: How did you start these images?   Did you try  *docker run hello-world*  or            *docker --version*  ?

Comment: Is docker installed within WSL?

Comment: Yes docker is installed in WSL and this command worked earlier. Actually, I did not do anything and waited for around 30minutes and then the command worked again. I am just unsure why it is not reliably working

Comment: @AdiDembak when running this, this is the beginning of the output I get: `Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world`